# How can I obtain transformation matrix of a quantum circuit in the Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, circuit-construction

I need to draw a quantum circuit in Clifford+T library and obtain automatically its transformation matrix. Is there any feature on Qiskit in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is great.

But here is a link that walk you through the process step-by-step: https://medium.com/mdr-inc/checking-the-unitary-matrix-of-the-quantum-circuit-on-qiskit-5968c6019a45

Answer (score 19):

While you can get the unitary matrix representation of a circuit using the unitary simulator as shown in the other answers, there is a much easier way using the `Operator` class in the `qiskit.quantum_info` library.

```
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi

op = qi.Operator(circ)
```

If you want the numpy array of the operator, this can be obtained via the `data` attribute (`array = op.data`)

See the [API Documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Operator.html#qiskit.quantum_info.Operator) and [Operator tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/2_operators_overview.html) for additional info on this class.

Answer (score 4):

In qiskit, you can get the unitary transformation matrix from a quantum circuit by running the following:

```
from qiskit import *
#circuit already defined
backend = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
job = execute(circuit, backend)
result = job.result()
print(result.get_unitary(circ, decimals=3))
```

and the matrix will output. As you increase the number of qubits in your circuit, the size of the unitary matrix will increase exponentially.