# How can I obtain a unitary matrix of quantum circuit with angles as parametric?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I need to draw a quantum circuit in Clifford+T library and obtain automatically its transformation matrix. (I received a response to this part of my question before in the link: [How can I obtain transformation matrix of a quantum circuit in the Qiskit?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/how-can-i-obtain-transformation-matrix-of-a-quantum-circuit-in-the-qiskit)) and now I want to do this work as a parametric. For example, I want to define gate T as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & w
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $w=\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}$, and I want to obtain the transformation matrix of the circuit with parameter $w$ and not as numeric. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As of Qiskit 0.23.0 that's not yet supported.

The reason is mainly that such a simulator would be very slow as we would have to use SymPy's matrix multiplication for symbolic expressions. This is not really feasible for more than 5 or 6 qubits -- depending on your machine specs. Also, the output can become a gigantic symbolic expression pretty quickly and therefore likely only of limited use.

That being said, you can of course write your own script for a symbolic simulator: all you have to do is replace matrix multiplications with SymPy multiplications. A good starting point could be the [`quantum_info.Operator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Operator.html) that uses straightforward NumPy multiplications and could probably be generalized easily.

Comment: Could you please send an example of what you are saying? thanks